# How to deploy and distribute a new Java Application Software - Starting from Simple yet Effective techniques to a Detailed & Professional ways

Tags: java, deployment, software-distribution, digital-certificate, jar-signing

I have developed my first version of **Java Desktop Application Software** for an 'electrical device' of my company and got to **plan proper deployment and distribution of our Application**. Right now it has 8 class files in one package and is dependent on 2 external libraries.

I have been through a lot of information available in many websites and blogs including Oracle, StackOverflow, wikipedia, workaround.org, excelsior-usa.com, particular software's home-site and many more and found the following steps to build, deploy and distribute my app:

1. Create a simple executable jar
2. Add signing configuration and verify
3. Add Versions and verify for backward compatibility
4. add time-stamp and verify
5. add certificates (either self signed or from a CA) and verify
6. use a build tool like gradle or maven to achieve the above to some extent
7. Or use launchers and wrappers like java-packager or install anywhere or install shield etc...
8. use AOT compilers like GCJ or Excelsior JET
9. Password protect the app and distribute passwords securely
10. distribute app on our own website or some standard ones

But I am really confused with overwhelming knowledge, too many options available and whether am in the right direction regarding these steps. I want to cross check the info and knowledge I have gained - with the same from experts like you...

Also as its the 1st version of app, I am bothered about how efficient it works & gets reviews from users, than about deployment. Right now, I think, its okey to deploy with minimum security and standards required and slowly invest more knowledge, money and time on deployment...

So please do guide me with

1. Simple, Effective and Free techniques to Deploy and Distribute Java Desktop Application Software(if possible, along-with codes I have to include in my manifest and app's main class)
2. Then later, how to Step by Step improve the app more secured and standardised with consecutive release of versions...
3. At last arrive to a state where the app becomes perfect and complete by all means and becomes a real professional software.(By that time, may be in next 9-12 months, my app will be in its last stage, which would be large and complex enough)

Comment: StackOverflow is for practical programming questions. Your question in its current form is too broad, that's why people vote to close it. You might want to split your question to parts. Also, "give me the code" or "provide a guide" questions are not much welcome on StackOverflow and they are usually closed as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response Eugene Mayevski..! I will edit my question and try to make it small... But I think I have to wait, if some one answers me for "Provide a guide", coz thats my need right now..! Also the reason behind posting this broad question is that - I wanted to tell you people that I have tried to gain knowledge, but as this is the first time I am Deploying and Distributing an Application, I just want to confirm I am in the right direction..!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found what I needed... A real big Index of Everything about Java where the index itself gives a broader perspective of where I am now in the Ocean and which way to go...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html

I believe, if I go through "Trail: Deployment" & "Trail: Security Features in Java SE" along with some other concepts like "RMI" I think I get a real complete idea of Deployment. Then I can decide on everything based on my app and needs...

Whenever I searched for "how to deploy and distribute Java desktop application", I have got either

a part of this index

or extended thoughts based on these concepts

or third party tools working around these basic ideas.

These random pages and more restricted discussions created a lot of ambiguity in understanding the concept. Even while learning I was dependent on books & never bothered of even knowing about ReallyBigIndex... I hope, now I am on the right track..